# Error Importing CSV list into Office 365 Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, import, csv

I'm trying to add a list to the Office 365 SharePoint application by importing a CSV. After selecting my range of cells and starting the import, I am thrown this error:

`cannot connect to the server at this time. your table cannot be published`

I've seen information on this error related to hosted SharePoint solutions, but this is the Office 365 version that I'm having issues with, so I can't imagine server configurations beeing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are using a 32-bit version of Internet Explorer 10 or 11 to import a spreadsheet. Importing a spreadsheet relies on ActiveX. Once the list is imported, you can then work with the list in any SharePoint supported browser.

Add the SharePoint site to the trusted sites list and compare the results.

In addition, check if you can [export the table to SharePoint list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-an-Excel-table-to-SharePoint-974544f9-94bc-4aa8-9159-97282d256dab).

Useful information: [Create a list based on a spreadsheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa).

Comment: Marking this as correct, it came the closest. I needed an updated version of Excel as well.